# ASP.Net HtmlTable - any equivilent to <col></col>?

Tags: asp.net

Is there an equivilent in ASP.Net Table or HtmlTable to the <col></col> element set in HTML to apply a style or class to an entire column?  Ideally I am looking to do this programmatically for a WebPart rather than in the ASP.Net designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HtmlTable could contain [HtmlGenericControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(VS.71).aspx), which gives you a col:

```
var t = new HtmlTable();
t.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("col"));
```

Answer (score 0):

According http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable(v=VS.100).aspx, the `<col>` is not supported in HtmlTable. So the only way to do this is to override the `RenderChildren()` method.

```
Private Class MyHtmlTable
    Inherits HtmlTable

    Private _tableDefinitionCells As New ControlCollection(Me)
    Public ReadOnly Property TableDefinitionCells As ControlCollection
        Get
            Return Me._tableDefinitionCells
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub RenderChildren(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        For Each c In Me._tableDefinitionCells.OfType(Of Control)()
            c.RenderControl(writer)
        Next

        MyBase.RenderChildren(writer)
    End Sub

End Class
```

You could use this like

```
Dim table = New MyHtmlTable()
table.TableDefinitionCells.Add(New HtmlGenericControl("col"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subclass of Table that renders `<col />` tags for each column:

```
public sealed class ColTable : Table
{
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GetColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Col);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }
        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }

    private int GetColumnCount()
    {
        int maxCount = 0;
        foreach (TableRow row in Rows)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                count += Math.Max(1, cell.ColumnSpan);
            }
            maxCount = Math.Max(count, maxCount);
        }
        return maxCount;
    }
}
```